# In a prepared statement, do you have to specify all parameters as ?, including mysql functions?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Say I have this query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table(one, two, date) VALUES (1, 2,  CURDATE())";
```

When rewritten for a prepared statement would it look like this?:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table(one, two, date) VALUES (?, ?,  CURDATE())";
OR
$query = "INSERT INTO table(one, two, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

And on bind_param, leave out the MySQL function or include it?:

```
...
$stmt->bind_param('ii', 1, 2);
OR
$stmt->bind_param('iis', 1, 2, 'CURDATE()');
```

Comment: The documentation would suffice along with a bit of experimentation.

Comment: You cannot parameterize mysql functions. Leave that as is.

Comment: If you tried the last example above you would probably find that `'CURDATE()'` is treated as a string, not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Iff you would bind function calls, that would mean any user input could be interpreted as a function. E.g.:

```
$stmt->bind_param('iis', 1, 2, 'CURDATE()');
```

```
$date = 'CURDATE()';
$stmt->bind_param('iis', 1, 2, $date);
```

```
$stmt->bind_param('iis', 1, 2, $someUserValue);
```

Which would be inherently insecure and the same as simple insecure string interpolation.

No, any bound parameter is some sort of primitive value, e.g. a string or integer or such. Never any structural part or code, which includes function calls. Remember, `bind_param('s', 'CURDATE()')` is equivalent to `VALUES(..., 'CURDATE()')`, not `VALUES(..., CURDATE())`.

Comment: Potential spelling mistake on your first word unless it is acronymised?

Comment: Thank you @deceze. Apologies, this was a poorly thought out and written question, your answer was very clear thank you. I experimented the mysql function call can be left as is in the initial query whilst user input variables are to be sanitised and bound.